# Blademail damage return type

Tags: dota-2, dota

What is the damage return type of blademail? Does it matches the type of the damage source or has a fixed damage type(chaos,hero, magical or pure)?

Comment: Merlini got this wrong in a recent cast... surprised me. =o

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The damage returned is pure type. The amount of damage applied is the same as the enemy hero actually took.

As of patch 6.87, magic immunity no longer blocks the returned damage from Blademail. Also the damage returned is applied before any damage reduction, and matches the damage source. Physical damage will be returned as physical, magic as magic, and pure as pure.

Comment: What does this mean:The pure type means you can block damage from blade mail with a Black King Bar? Block or you mean return?

Comment: @UlfricStormcloak Pure is a type of magical damage that ignore your armor and your magic resistance. 400pure damage means you will loose 400HP no matter what. Black King Bar grant magic imunity for a certain amount of time. As the damage returned from blade mail is pure (so magical), you wont take any damage from a blade mailed enemy whil your bkb is on.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Dota2 Wiki](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Blade_Mail)

The damage return is Pure.

The amount of damage returned is what you received after armor and magic resistance is calculated.

Comment: Pure but reduced? Then it's not pure? I don't get it. Can you give me link?

Comment: @UlfricStormcloak Provided link in answer :) Although I think it is in reference to the incoming damage.

Comment: Yes, I am asking for the 'returned damage'.

Comment: I think an example would help here. Eg Hero A casts a 100 dmg, magic resistance takes that down to 75 dmg, which gets reflected as pure damage

Comment: In other words, having more armor or more magic resistance on a hero makes buying Blademail on that hero less effective.

Comment: Aha.. so if you are to use a blademail, a hero must have higher HP instead of a high armor.